# О запятой перед "и" в сложном предложении

Tags: сложное-предложение, и

Не понимаю, для чего в параграфе о запятой в сложносочиненном предложении (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133) написано следующее:

"Примечание. Перед союзом "и" запятая ставится также в тех случаях, когда он присоединяет предложение, в котором подлежащее выражено личным местоимением, относящимся к подлежащему первой части сложносочиненного предложения или повторяющим его".

Может, я чего-то не вижу? Какая разница, чем выражены подлежащие? Они просто есть, поэтому ставим запятую (в обычном случае).

Comment: Кто-то может подумать, что запятая не нужна, раз тот же производитель действия. Это для таких людей.

Comment: @Sharon  Конечно, этот вопрос связан с тем, так как Jim Korbett дал ссылку на правило. Но Ваш ответ я понял, как мне кажется, правильно. Вы говорите о повторе местоимений, одно из которых не является подлежащим. Спасибо за ссылку, скопировал, обязательно прочитаю позже.

Comment: @Sharon Аа, я об этом не раз говорил. Это когда вторая часть ссылается на первую (зависимость).

Comment: @Sharon Вы так красиво пишете в своих статьях. Будто совсем другой человек. Это сложно? Почему бы так всегда не писать? А то куча опечаток, ошибок, логических нестыковок. А там всё выверено, логично. Вы же умеете.

Comment: Спасибо!  Здесь сырой материал, а там обдуманный, обобщенный, много раз проверенный. Я часто обращаюсь к этим статейкам (если их читают) и много раз их правлю. Проверяю впечатление, как будто сама читаю первый раз. Так что долгий это труд...

Comment: @Sharon, я вот тоже прочитал. Понравилось! Только чуточку хочется подправить (есть лишние кавычки, а в другом месте не хватает; пробела нет перед скобкой). Это я так, к вопросу об идеале.:)) Но в одном месте явно нужно исправить:  "...это  будущее и настоящее время (потребуется, прошла)" – там "прошла" из придаточного, а нужно "не можем вернуть".

Comment: Спасибо, Александр, обязательно посмотрю ваши замечания чуть позже, спасибо за все ваши правки.  Вы так внимательны, это уже профессиональное качество, а у меня так не получается. И  правлю я в основном стиль и содержание (ну чтобы читателям нравиться) :)

Answer (score 0):

Он  имел ввиду, что запятая ставится, несмотря на общее сочетание. Там два примера, и оба они с общим сочетание. По какой-то причине Розенталь не написал это напрямую, а это примечание не перенёс в пункт про общее сочетание. На мой взгляд, это грубейшая небрежность из разряда – лень было перепроверить учебное пособие, прежде чем опубликовать.

Comment: Нет, он не имел это в виду. Просто попались такие примеры.

Comment: В оригинальном справочнике есть третий пример, без общего: *Он познакомился с ним в Дели, и нынче он ехал с ним в Лахор.*

Comment: Во-первых, автор вопроса правильно заметил, что зачем вообще тогда писать это примечание, если оно является частью общего пункта о запятой между сложносочинённым – какая разница местоимение там или нет, куда оно относится, когда мы и так ставим запятую между сложносочинённым. Во-вторых, попалось ДВА примера, а не один.

Comment: Если бы это касалось общего, то было бы сказано о общем и было бы в другом параграфе. Мы ставим запятую между предложениями, в которых разные подлежащие. А здесь как бы то же подлежащее, оно не меняется. Кого-то это может сбить с толку. В связи с этим было написано данное примечание.

Comment: А почему тогда, несмотря на общее сочетание, в примерах запятая?

Comment: Например, в английском запятая в таких случаях обычно не ставится.

Comment: Занимательная информация.

Comment: Это не простой вопрос. Когда человек называет два действия, он не будет повторять объект. Например, никто не скажет: *Сегодня я куплю сгущёнку и я сделаю торт.* А если повторяет, то это уже новая мысль.

Comment: Нет, это не та ситуация. Это типично, когда что-то обозначается одним словом, а потом это же обозначается местоимением в следующем предложении.  В вашем предложении будет ошибкой добавить местоимение, но во многих не это не будет такой ошибкой. Никто не сочтёт, что здесь не нужна запятая, когда это фактически два предложения.

Comment: Примеры в студию.

Comment: Такое предложение: ‟Там два примера, и оба они с общим сочетание”. Ещё: ‟У неё было два мужа, и оба они изменяли ей”.

Comment: "Оба" не трогайте, оно присоединение создаёт ("и притом оба").

Comment: Правила гласят о нескольких (если не о разных) подлежащих, а здесь то же. Могут сочти. Справочник для всех, не только для умных.